# AngularJS: binding to ng-repeat blurs the input inside the repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a similar problem to this one here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/eB19TlFHFVE/Rlh--XImXeYJ

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KGu9n/25/

My problem is that I also have a save function that gets called as the user is typing.

So I have something like this (where there may be manipulation to $scope.piece.movements in the backend.  When the object comes back as response.data, it re-sets the $scope.piece.movements and it loses focus at that point.

```
$scope.save = function () {
$http.post('/save/', { object: $scope.piece.movements }).then(function (response) {
      $scope.piece.movements = response.data; // loses focus here
 });
};
```

Any help would be great!  And if someone knows how I can simulate a post/save in fiddle/plnkr, I will gladly update my fiddle.

Comment: Why not just $watch piece.movements for changes and post those changes to a save service/factory.

Comment: Maybe something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xmltechgeek/HbDDf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a function it would be preferable here to to use $watch for changes to pieces. Then in watch you can perform logic to determine if this is the right time (see timeout logic) to trigger changes and call out to a factory to perform the save. As shown here http://jsfiddle.net/xmltechgeek/HbDDf/ this works without loosing focus.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('controller', function($scope, $timeout, dummy) {
        $scope.piece = {};
        $scope.piece.movements = [{name: "Allegro"} , {name: "Presto"}];

        var saveTimeout;
        $scope.$watch('piece.movements', function(){
            $timeout.cancel(saveTimeout)
            saveTimeout = $timeout(function(){
                dummy.save($scope.piece.movements, function(data){
                    $scope.piece.movements = data;
                    console.log($scope.piece.movements);
                })
            }, 1500);
        }, true);

    })
.factory('dummy', function(){
    var changes = {
        content: "",
        save: function(content, callback){
            this.content = content;
            callback(this.content);
        },
        get: function() {
            return this.content;
        }
    };
    return changes;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I can't use a $watch because I don't want it to get fired on every letter.  I have it fire a save when the user stops typing.  How would you handle that?

Comment: Updated based on a timeout that will only trigger if the user hasn't been typing for x time (1.5 seconds in the example). Other logic styles could be used as well.